# Force remote to checkout branch

Tags: git, deployment

We currently deploy to a dev server via Git with a post-receive hook. It is a dev server rather than a staging server so we would like to be able to deploy/view multiple branches (rather than just a "dev" branch or somethng similar).

When a new branch or commit is pushed the post-receive hook successfully performs a checkout on the remote repo to whatever branch is pushed.

Our typical cycle might be:

View new branch1 on dev server - `git push devserver branch1`

View new branch2 on dev server - `git push devserver branch2`

View old branch1 on dev server again - `git push devserver branch1`

However when we would like to checkout to an branch older branch than the current active one we cannot do `git push devserver branch1` because the remote repo responds with "Everything up-to-date" since `branch1` has already been pushed a while ago. Obviously the post-receive hook is not run so is there another way to action the remote checkout?

I know I can SSH into the dev server and checkout to the `branch1` that way but I would like to perform the action from my local repo if possible. I have tried the pre-receive and update hooks but neither of those seem to run in this circumstances.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is just a (dev) server, why don't you delete the branch and recreate it?

```
git push devserver :branch1
git push devserver branch1
```

Comment: very nice, didn't think about it

Answer (score 0):

Controlling a remote working copy is very limited, since git isn't really made for this, so you have to SSH the server. Make a small script to connect and  checkout will save you time and finger muscles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking up the same script as a [pre-receive hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) too. This means that your script will run regardless of whether your push command is successful or not. That said, I'd be really wary of this kind of stuff, because what you're doing now is using hooks in a manner that they were not designed to be used and possibly digging a hole for yourself in the future.

The real solution would be what @CharlesB suggested - use a simple script.

EDIT: Please ignore this answer. This will not work, as the comments suggest. Feel free to downvote too ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've tried using the pre-receive hook but it doesn't seem to do anything. There was no pre-receive.sample file by default (as there was with the others) so I dont suppose you know if need to do something to enable it?

Comment: you seem to imply that pre-receive hook runs even when it says everything is up-to-date and doesn't push any ref. That is not the case.

Comment: @atkaye - My comment was at carleeto, but yeah, what you observe in case of pre-receive is correct. It will not work as expected. See my answer if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The pre-receive hook is not the right mechanism for this.